# jQuery UI - Drag function callback offset not updating on drag event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, offset, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using jQuery drag and drop to build an application for designing layouts so it needs to be 100% accurate. The problem I am having is that the draggables position seems to be calculated before the drag event. So the position logged once the element is dropped is always slightly out.

For example: I position the draggable 10px from the top of the droppable, and 10px from the left then drop it. When I check the top and left position in Chrome inspector it shows as 10px from the top and 9px from the left.

I have set up a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/ELS8A/3/

See code below (this is taken from a much larger project):

HTML:

```
<div class="boundary"></div>
<div class="drag"></div>

<p class="clone_pos">|</p>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
.boundary {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:lightblue
}
.drag {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:pink;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var in_boundary = false;

jQuery('.drag').draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid',
    drag : function ( event, ui ) { dragging(ui); },
});

jQuery('.boundary').droppable({
    drop: function (ev, ui) { drop_it(this, ui); },
    accept: '.drag',
    tolerance: 'fit',
    over : function( event, ui ) { inside_boundary(ui.helper); },
    out : function( event, ui ) { outside_boundary(ui.helper); },
});

function drop_it(boundary, clone) {
    b_offset = jQuery(boundary).offset(); //get the boundary offset x, y
    b_top = b_offset.top;
    b_left = b_offset.left;

    d_offset_left = (clone.offset.left - b_left); //set positioning for dropped
    d_offset_top = (clone.offset.top - b_top);

    d_clone = jQuery(clone.helper).clone(false) //clone helper
    .removeClass('ui-draggable-dragging') //remove dragging classes
    .removeClass('ui-draggable') //remove dragging classes
    .css({
        position: 'absolute',
        left: d_offset_left,
        top: d_offset_top
    })

    jQuery(boundary).append(d_clone); //append clone to boundary
}

function inside_boundary(this_elem){
    in_boundary = true;
    jQuery(this_elem).css('background', 'blue'); 
}

function outside_boundary(this_elem){
    in_boundary = false;
    jQuery(this_elem).css('background', 'pink');
}        

function dragging(this_ui){ 
    if( in_boundary ){//in_boundary? then start tracking coords 
        boundary = jQuery('.boundary');
        this_draggable = this_ui.helper;//get reference to clone

        b = get_trbl(boundary, 'absolute');//t, r, b, l of boundary
        clone = get_trbl(this_draggable, 'absolute');//t, r, b, l of clone

        clone['top'] -= b['top'];//get clone coords relative to boundary        
        clone['left'] -= b['left'];
        jQuery('.clone_pos').text('TOP: '+clone['top']+', LEFT: '+clone['left']);
    }
}

function get_trbl(elem){//get top, right, bottom, left offset
    tmp = {};
    elem_offset = elem.offset();

    elem_top = elem_offset.top;
    elem_left = elem_offset.left;
    elem_right = elem_left + elem.width();
    elem_bottom = elem_top + elem.height();

    tmp['left'] = elem_left;
    tmp['top'] = elem_top;
    tmp['right'] = elem_right;
    tmp['bottom'] = elem_bottom;
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: Why are you manipulating/calculating the positions? can't get the actual position values using the `position()` method? i think you're over complicating things...

Comment: @Tilwin- thanks, but in the real case scenario I am dragging elements from a relatively positioned element, and dropping them into another relatively positioned element. Using position only gives me its position relative to its parent whereas I needed it in relation to the drop area. This is why I'm using offset() for both and then calculating relative positions.